# I have 2 different folder names in my local and remote Bitbucket repo. What should I do?

Tags: git, bitbucket

The problem:

In my remote repo, I have folder names in capital letter while on my local machine, I have lowercase folder names.

`git status` says that everything is up to date.

I've tried to delete my remote branch and make a push from the local. But everything stayed the same.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @JimRedmond macOS

Comment: What filesystem, and is it case-sensitive? (You may need to look at Disk Utility for that.)

Comment: I guess, I've figured it out

Answer (score 0):

[Given this little piece of data](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/renaming-a-file-for-case-under-git-source-control-is-not-updated-by-sourcetree-on-mac-os-x-302809301.html) it seems kind of logical now, (although, really frustrating)

The problem is caused due to the default Mac OS filesystem which is `generally case insensitive`.

There's no other way but to make 2 dummy commits: renaming a folder/file to something else and renaming it back

Answer (score 0):

You should not need 2 commits: 2 git mv (within the index) should be enough:

```
git mv foldername tempname && git mv tempname folderName
```

Then commit.